# In MySQL how to write SQL to join two tables better than a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Lets say I have two MySQL tables, purchase_log, which is a record of all client payments, and game_log, a record of all games played.

```
create table purchase_log (
  client_id int, 
  purchase_date date,
  amount int
);

insert into purchase_log (client_id, purchase_date, amount) values (9, '2012-01-01', 10);
insert into purchase_log (client_id, purchase_date, amount) values (10, '2012-01-01', 5);
insert into purchase_log (client_id, purchase_date, amount) values (11, '2012-01-01', 10);

create table game_log (
  client_id int, 
  game_id int,
  game_date date
);

insert into game_log (client_id, game_id, game_date) values (9, 110, '2012-12-01');
insert into game_log (client_id, game_id, game_date) values (10, 110, '2012-12-01');
insert into game_log (client_id, game_id, game_date) values (11, 110, '2012-12-01');
insert into game_log (client_id, game_id, game_date) values (11, 110, '2012-12-02');
insert into game_log (client_id, game_id, game_date) values (11, 110, '2012-12-03');
```

What is the average amount of money spent by clients, grouped by month, but only for clients that played a game?

```
select avg(amount)
from purchase_log
where client_id in 
            (select client_id
             from game_log
             #where...
             )
#and...
group by month(purchase_date);

+-------------+
| avg(amount) |
+-------------+
|      8.3333 |
+-------------+
```

This answer of 8.3 is correct. ((10+10+5)/3 = 8.3) But many SO articles say joins are more efficient, so I rewrite into a join:

```
select avg(amount)
from purchase_log p
#where...
join game_log g on p.client_id=g.client_id
#and...
group by month(purchase_date);

+-------------+
| avg(amount) |
+-------------+
|      9.0000 |
+-------------+
```

But that result of 9.0 is wrong, it should be 8.3.  The join gives a wrong result because one client played multiple games, which gives 3 rows.

Is there a way I can fix this join?  Or should I go back to the less efficient subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to try this query is:

```
select avg(amount)
from purchase_log pl
where exits (select 1
             from game_log gl
             where gl.client_id = pl.client_id
             );
```

For this to work well, you also want an index on `game_log(client_id)`.

Your result is different because the `join` multiplies the number of rows.  This is a case where it is really easier to keep the condition in the `where` clause.